# Unable to merge two tables using join or union

Tags: mysql, join

These is my tables:
`SELECT * FROM TableA`
and `SELECT * FROM TableB`

```
    Table A             Table B
    +-------+------+    +-------+------+ 
    | FileA | StepA|    | FileB | StepB|
    +-------+------+    +-------+------+ 
    |  001  |  1   |    |  001  |   1  |
    |  001  |  2   |    |  001  |   2  |
    |  001  |  3   |    |  001  |   3  |
    |  001  |  4   |    |  002  |   1  |
    |  001  |  5   |    |  002  |   2  |    
    |  002  |  1   |    |  002  |   3  |    
    |  002  |  2   |    |  003  |   1  |
    |  002  |  3   |    +-------+------+
    |  002  |  4   |    
    |  002  |  5   |  
    |  004  |  1   |    
    |  004  |  2   |    
    |  004  |  3   | 
    |  004  |  4   |    
    |  004  |  5   |
    +-------+------+
```

My result:

```
SELECT * FROM TableA AS TA LEFT JOIN TableB AS TB ON TA.FileA != TB.FileB GROUP BY TA.FileA ORDER BY TA.StepA ASC

    +-------+------+-------+------+ 
    | FileA | StepA| FileA | StepB|
    +-------+------+-------+------+ 
    |  001  |  1   |  001  |   1  |
    |  001  |  2   |  001  |   1  |
    |  001  |  3   |  001  |   1  |
    |  001  |  4   |  001  |   1  |
    |  001  |  5   |  001  |   1  |  
    +-------+------+-------+------+
```

But this is my expected result:

```
    +-------+------+-------+------+ 
    | FileA | StepA| FileB | StepB|
    +-------+------+-------+------+ 
    |  001  |  1   |  001  |   1  |
    |  001  |  2   |  001  |   2  |
    |  001  |  3   |  001  |   3  |
    |  001  |  4   |  null | null |
    |  001  |  5   |  null | null |
    |  002  |  1   |  002  |   1  |    
    |  002  |  2   |  002  |   2  |    
    |  002  |  3   |  002  |   3  |       
    |  002  |  4   |  null | null |       
    |  002  |  5   |  null | null |  
    |  null | null |  003  |   1  |          
    |  004  |  1   |  null | null |    
    |  004  |  2   |  null | null |      
    |  004  |  3   |  null | null |    
    |  004  |  4   |  null | null |      
    |  004  |  5   |  null | null |    
    +-------+------+-------+------+
```

Is it possible to do these with joins or union so that I can have these output?

Comment: You are using a non-equijoin. Are you sure you want to join tables on a rule like that?

Answer (score 0):

I think these SQL useful to you.

```
    SELECT * FROM (

       SELECT * FROM tablea AS TA LEFT JOIN tableb AS TB 
    ON TA.FileA = TB.FileB AND TA.stepA= TB.stepB 

UNION
     SELECT * FROM tablea AS TA RIGHT JOIN tableb AS TB 
    ON TA.FileA = TB.FileB AND TA.stepA= TB.stepB ) a
  ORDER BY FileA, stepA,fileb ASC
```

Thank you.

Comment: Make that a full outer join.

Comment: I already tried it, but it did not reflect to my expected output.

Comment: It almost reach the result but I think it only considers the table A. but still not my required output.

Comment: in output what your problem. ordering  the data?

Comment: not only the ordering but also the null values for each column just like what I pointed to my expected results.

Comment: Incorrect usage of union and full outer join syntax cannot read. Im just using MySQL Workbench.

Comment: can you provide sql fiddle please. I will work on that i will give you exact query.

Comment: Im trying but I am not familiar with that fiddle

Comment: Im currently here at office social media is not allowed, im sorry but this is my only problem so that I can finish my project. thanks for help.

Comment: you satisfy my answer can you give a blue tick mark please.

Comment: Thanks but please stay put im just trying to figure out multiple data.

Comment: @VenkateshPanabaka: is full outer join exists in mysql?

Comment: @ZafarMalik sorry it's not available.

Comment: It was good at the example but if I will simulate to different kinds of data, it will duplicate some of tableA to fill all in tableB. In short it is not consistent.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to order your values this way, you can use a coalesce() on a sub-query:

```
SELECT 
    sub.`FileA`, 
    sub.`StepA`, 
    sub.`FileB`, 
    sub.`StepB` 
FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            ta.`FileA`, 
            ta.`StepA`, 
            tb.`FileB`, 
            tb.`StepB`, 
            coalesce(ta.`FileA`, tb.`FileB`) AS `File`, 
            coalesce(ta.`StepA`, tb.`StepB`) AS `Step` 
        FROM 
            `TableA` ta 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN `TableB` tb ON (
                ta.`FileA` = tb.`FileB` 
                AND ta.`StepA` = tb.`StepB`
            ) 
        UNION 
        SELECT 
            ta.`FileA`, 
            ta.`StepA`, 
            tb.`FileB`, 
            tb.`StepB`, 
            coalesce(ta.`FileA`, tb.`FileB`) AS `File`, 
            coalesce(ta.`StepA`, tb.`StepB`) AS `Step` 
        FROM 
            `TableA` ta 
            RIGHT OUTER JOIN `TableB` tb ON (
                ta.`FileA` = tb.`FileB` 
                AND ta.`StepA` = tb.`StepB`
            )
    ) sub
ORDER BY 
    sub.`File` ASC, 
    sub.`Step` ASC
```

More information on [COALESCE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)